# How to make cache repository thread safe

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, repository-pattern

I have the the following Repository with cache

```
  public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserRepository
{
    User GetUser(int userId);
}

public class CacheObject
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}

public class CachedUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    private List<CacheObject> _cache = new List<CacheObject>();

    private int _cacheDuration = 60;

    public CachedUserRepository(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    public User GetUser(int userId)
    {
        bool addToCache = false;
        CacheObject valueFromCache = _cache.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
        // user was found
        if (valueFromCache != null)
        {
            // if cache is outdated then remove value from it
            if (valueFromCache.CreationDate.AddSeconds(_cacheDuration) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                _cache.Remove(valueFromCache);
                addToCache = true;
            }
            else {
                // update  cache date
                valueFromCache.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                return valueFromCache.User;
            }
        }
        // user is absent in cache
        else {
            addToCache = true;
        }

        if (addToCache)
        {
            User result = _userRepository.GetUser(userId);
            _cache.Add(new CacheObject() { User = result, UserId = userId, CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I would like to run method GetUser() in different threads so i need to make this method thread safe. 
**How can i make it ?** 
I don't see any elegant solution , only lock(someObject) to the whole method body. But as result i will not achieve any performance gain

Comment: Can't you use the .Net framework provided cache? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx It is entirely thread safe. See http://blog.falafel.com/working-system-runtime-caching-memorycache/ for an example

Comment: @PeterBons MemoryCache of course can be used instead of my custom approach with List and CreationDate. But some locking is still needed.

Comment: Is your repository itself thread-safe? If not, then it seems pointless to me.

Comment: @Maarten. Repository is thread safe

Answer (score 0):

We usually do this with a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
public class CachedUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    private List<CacheObject> _cache = new List<CacheObject>();

    private int _cacheDuration = 60;

    public CachedUserRepository(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    public User GetUser(int userId)
    {
        bool addToCache = false;
        // Enter an upgradeable read lock because we might have to use a write lock if having to update the cache
        // Multiple threads can read the cache at the same time
        _cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
        try
        {
            CacheObject valueFromCache = _cache.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
            // user was found
            if (valueFromCache != null)
            {
                // if cache is outdated then remove value from it
                if (valueFromCache.CreationDate.AddSeconds(_cacheDuration) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    // Upgrade to a write lock, as an item has to be removed from the cache.
                    // We will only enter the write lock if nobody holds either a read or write lock
                    _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                    try
                    {
                        _cache.Remove(valueFromCache);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                    }
                    addToCache = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // update  cache date
                    valueFromCache.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
                    return valueFromCache.User;
                }
            }
            // user is absent in cache
            else
            {
                addToCache = true;
            }

            if (addToCache)
            {
                User result = _userRepository.GetUser(userId);
                // Upgrade to a write lock, as an item will (probably) be added to the cache.
                // We will only enter the write lock if nobody holds either a read or write lock
                _cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                    if (_cache.Any(u => u.UserId != userId))
                    {
                        _cache.Add(new CacheObject() {User = result, UserId = userId, CreationDate = DateTime.Now});
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

With this, multiple threads will be able to read the cache simultaneously, but if it has to be written, it will get locked.

Disclaimer: I haven't run the code to check it ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do i need to use some thread safe collection for cache objects instead of List(as it is now) ?

Comment: You can use a List, as you guarantee write access to the List by only 1 thread at a time. You'll have to use a write lock when removing an item from the cache and probably want to re-check if the item has not already been added (by an other thread) in the write lock

Comment: "You can use a List, as you guarantee write access to the List by only 1 thread at a time". Can i be sure that multiple simultaneous reads from List will not crash ?

Comment: We release read lock only in the end. How then we can enter to write lock ?! It seems we should release read lock earlier.

Comment: You'll have ConcurrentModificationExceptions when writing the cache while reading it, so it is safe. While being in a UpgradeableReadLock, you can enter a write lock

Comment: So in case with two threads when first read something and second write something "_cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();" will throw exception and "add" operation will never be executed

Comment: Nope, to enter a write lock nobody is allowed to hold either a read or write lock (only an upgradeable read lock). Have a look at the msdn remark for details.

Comment: Maybe i am totally stupid, but i still don't understand. From msdn - "A thread that tries to enter upgradeable mode blocks if there is already a thread in upgradeable mode". So actually your code will be executed only by one thread, because your enter upgradeable mode in the beginning of function and release it in the end